# how to add a textfield dynamically after clicking a button in iphone

Tags: iphone

How to add a textfields dynamically on clicking the button?

when clicking on the button textfield should appear with scrollview.

can anyone explain me how to do?

Comment: Hey Venki i think now you got your answer than accept it

Answer (score 1):

what have you tried??
May be this is what you are asking for.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    UITextField *textField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 40, 21)];
    [scrollView addSubview:textField];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}
```

EDIT

IF not dynamically,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    UITextField *textField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 40, 21)];
    [scrollView addSubview:textField];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView setHidden:YES];
}

-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [scrollView setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: This is for dynamically,now need without dynamically.on clicking on the button two textfields should appear with a scrollview

Comment: you can use the Hidden property to achive this ,I will edit my answer

Comment: Check my updated answer,and yeah ,accept the answer if it is what you are looking for

Comment: my textfields should be behind the button after clicking on the button only i should get the two textfields.what ever the code you edited that hides my view.

Comment: first create  a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

In Button action, you can create the dynamic textfields and them to your scrollview.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to add Text Field programmatically..

```
UITextField * aTextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; // give your frame
aTextfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
aTextfield.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
aTextfield.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
aTextfield.placeholder = @"Suchen";
aTextfield.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
aTextfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
aTextfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
aTextfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
aTextfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
aTextfield.delegate = self;

[scrollview addSubview:aTextfield];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my code.

http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2012/09/make-textfield-and-label-dynamically-in.html

According to this you can create number of textfield and label in scroll view, so you can change it according to your requirement.